# Googlemap api v3 slower than api v2?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am in the midst of converting old googlemap v2 code to v3 and it looks if v3 is much slower than v2?

Most of my code change is just replacing G with google.maps. (GMarker to google.maps.Marker)

Any tips or tricks how to speed things up??

Comment: what exactly is it that is slow? is it when you load tiles, data or what?

Comment: +1 for @igorti's comment:  What exactly is slow? And what does your code look like?

Comment: @igorti, it's slow upon loading the map. No data on map, just pure initialization.

Answer (score 7):

The solution might be as simple as experimenting with different versions of the v3 API by trying `v=3.4` and `v=3.5` in your links that load the API like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.5"></script>
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.4"></script>
```

On a site I built, the product manager felt that Streetview in particular was sluggish in 3.6.  When I rolled it back to 3.5, he felt that it was a noticeable improvement.

Comment: Trott, bounty goes to you, your answer was most interesting one, though I think my problem was in the Firebug.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use it unless you really need it. Never change a running system. Maybe you want to write a better marker solution with a better clustering (spatial index, quadtree, heatmap)? I.e. Google's fusion table doesn't support a spatial index. You want to look for Nick's spatial index hilbert curve quadtree blog.

Comment: hahaha, true, true but i might want to add some nice google features in the near future

Comment: I've corrected my answer. I'm just missing a spatial index and I don't think that v3 solved this.

Comment: This no longer applies as the fascist pigs that are Google are now officially deleting v2 next year.  Otherwise I would have agreed with you! Still, +1 as your advice is definitely sound!

Answer (score 0):

My problem probably was with using FireBug - then the V3 api is loading slower than V2. Also, switching between satellite and normal map makes slow fade effect when FireBug is on.